# Can't connect to to siteground database with SQL

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to connect to my siteground native database, but I'm getting this error:

> ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user
> 'root'@'cpc1234569-man6-2-1-cust215.7-1.cable.virginm.net' (using
> password: YES)

when I try to make a query. I'm connecting via mySQL's VSCode plugin.

I've entered my public IP address in to Siteground's remote access host section, but I'm still being denied permission. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried contacting SiteGround's support team yet? If not then it might be a good idea to do so, there might be a problem on their side preventing you from accessing the server remotely.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by creating a new database access account within the siteground tools page. There must have been something wrong with the credentials of the previous account passed on to me by my colleague. It worked smoothly from a new account.